# how can i make a sum in a line of numbers in python?

Tags: python, sum, line

i'm in trouble trying to calculate and appear the sum of a series of numbers in lines. it should be like this:

32565854 SUM: 38

65985456  SUM: 48

17984956  SUM: 49

Comment: have you tried anything code-wise? paste in please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can turn the line into string and then:

```
sum(map(int, '32565854'))
```

with a file:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        print line + ' ' + str(sum(map(int, line)))
```

Comment: It's lots of numbers and lines and I want to do this in a file which is called "numbers.txt". I use "f=open('numbers.txt')"

Comment: While iterating over each line, remember to remove the newline character at the end of it:
`line = line.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: it doesn't work!!

f=open('numbers.txt')
lines=f.readlines
for lines in f:
    print(lines+' '+str(sum(map(int, lines))))
    lines=lines.rstrip('\n')